# How to create a XML using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, xml

I want to copy the data from text area and want to create a `XML` using that data in `Jquery`.
To copied it from text area i wrote the following code in `Jquery`:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     function paste_data() {
         var text = $('#all').val();
         alert(text);

     }
</script>
```

// all is the id of the text area.

When i print the data it shows me in following format:

```
406450 8 first
43333  89 second
987 90 third-fourth
```

Now i want to create a `XML` using the above data in `javascript or Jquery` using the following format. So that i can use it further.

```
<row dc = "406450" al="8" msg="first" />
<row dc = "43333" al="89" msg="second" />
<row dc = "987" al="90" msg="third-forth" /> ....and so on
```

I don't know whether it is possible or not, but what about the split function?

Comment: you can surely split the format where ever you have a space in the string. but that means you trust the user to have made the input correct. Why not using 3 textboxes for every node in the xml?

Comment: @SvenBieder Actually i am newbie in Jquery and xml. Yes the user will enter into the above format. and didn't got the 3 textboxes example in xml

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can split it like this to get a 2-dimensional array

```
text = text.split('\n'); // split with newline to get the three lines separate
text = text.map(function(line) {
  return line.split(' ');
});
```

Now text should look like:

```
[
  [406450,8,'first'],
  [43333,89,'second'],
  [987,90,'third-fourth']
]
```

Now you parse that to strings and then concat the strings to form the document

```
var xml = text.map(function(arr) {
  return "<row dc='"+arr[0]+"' al='"+arr[1]+"' msg='"+arr[2]+"' />"   
});
xml = xml.join(''); // results in a well-formed xml-string, hopefully
```

Then just use jQuery's [`parseXML` -function](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseXML/) to form that into an xml-document

```
var xmlDoc = $.parseXML(xml);
```

Et voilà, now you have created a xml-document! Now if you want to manipulate that doc with jquery, just wrap it:

```
var $xmlDoc = $(xmlDoc);
```

Comment: well, `split` should produce an array and arrays have the function `map` (from Javascript 1.6 onwards). So `console.log` text to see if it truly is an array and what its contents are. If you're boasting some old version of chrome/firefox, then update asap and try again.